# Get values from Dynamic list

Tags: java, android

Good day everyone,

I'm learning Android development and I try to build some dynamic lists for my application. And I'm stuck... like for 4 hours already.

I have two layouts:
1. main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/action_buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_calculate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_count"
    android:text="@string/button_add" />
</LinearLayout>    

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_buttons"
    >      

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

1. action_list_item.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/action_list_item_root"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/action_list_item_edittext_drinkName"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/action_list_item_button_remove"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/action_list_item_title"
       android:padding="10dp" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/action_list_item_edittext_drinkPercent"
       android:text="40"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/action_list_item_edittext_drinkAmount"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:padding="10dp"/>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/action_list_item_edittext_drinkAmount"
       android:text="0.0"        
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/action_list_item_button_remove"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/action_list_item_button_remove"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal"      
       android:width="50dp"
       android:padding="10dp" />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/action_list_item_button_remove"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:text="@string/action_list_item_button_remove" />
   ```

And code that creates dynamic list:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  LinearLayout actionList = null;
  private Button btnAdd;
  private Button btnCalculate;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initActivityElements();

  }

  private void initActivityElements() {
    initAddButton();
    initCalculateButton();
  }

  private void initCalculateButton() {
    btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_count);
    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_list_item_edittext_drinkAmount);

//this retrives TextView value from first list
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), amount.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

      }
    });
  }

  private void initAddButton() {
    actionList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.action_list);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        RelativeLayout listItem = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.action_list_item, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) listItem
            .findViewById(R.id.action_list_item_edittext_drinkName);
        name.setText("Here is the Title " + actionList.getChildCount());

        listItem.findViewById(R.id.action_list_item_button_remove)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                actionList.removeView((View) v.getParent());
              }
            });

        actionList.addView(listItem);
      }
    });
  }
```

My problem is that I need to get all data from TextView boxes (Amount, Percent), but I can retrive that data only from first item of a list (look at onClickListener for **btnCalculate**) and can't figure out how to do it, but tried to add 'unique ids' for view (but that brakes layout, badly), tried setting Tags but again with no luck.

Maybe anyone can give a tip? I bet there is some easy way to do it, but I'm failing to find it and google is no help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to do but it sounds like you are trying to take in information and populate it into a view. I would recommend having a static text box that takes in your information and builds that into a listview. A good example of how to do that is located here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html.

Comment: these TextView's contain some default 'numbers', but i expect them to change (like title: vodka percent:40 amount:0,5).
In the end i will receive a list of drinks and  i need to process it.